# PHP XML Question

Tags: php, xml

My PHP:

```
$url = '../build.xml';
$xml = simplexml_load_file($url);

foreach($xml->css as $css) {
    echo (string) $css->element['id']."{";
    foreach($xml->css->element->csstag as $tag) {
        $temp = $tag->title.": ".$tag->value.";";
        echo $temp;
    }
    echo "}";
}
```

My XML:

```
<root>
    <css>
    <element id="body">
        <csstag><title>background-color</title><value>#FFF</value></csstag>
        <csstag><title>color</title><value>#333</value></csstag>
        <csstag><title>font-family</title><value>Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif</value></csstag>
    </element>
    <element id="#header">
        <csstag><title>background-color</title><value>#444</value></csstag>
        <csstag><title>color</title><value>#FFF</value></csstag>
        <csstag><title>border-bottom</title><value>#333 5px solid</value></csstag>
    </element>
    <element id="#footer">
        <csstag><title>background-color</title><value>#444</value></csstag>
        <csstag><title>color</title><value>#FFF</value></csstag>
        <csstag><title>border-top</title><value>#333 5px solid</value></csstag>
    </element>
    </css>
</root>
```

I can't find what's wrong!

The first issue is that the first foreach is showing just the first `<element>` node, I know that's because I've told it to foreach each `<css>` tag, but I couldn't think of any other way do echo the attribute of the `<element>` nodes.

The second thing is that the second foreach is echoing nothing back!

Can anyone see the problem in the code? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You're missing a foreach loop, you need another level

```
foreach($xml->css as $css) {
    foreach($xml->css->element as $elem){ // foreach element
        echo (string) $elem['id']."{";    // id for each element
        foreach($elem->csstag as $tag) {
            $temp = $tag->title.": ".$tag->value.";";
            echo $temp;
    }
    echo "}\n"; //\n to make the css look neater
    }
}
```